Why does it cost to hedge?
In e.g. https://www.nb.com/en/ae/insights/the-opportunity-in-usd-hedged-global-treasuries it says

A EUR-based investor who purchases a U.S. Treasury, for example, will currently give up around 310 basis points annually to insulate
themselves from currency movements: this consists of the 260-basis point short rate (3-month USD LIBOR) paid away for selling the
USD, the negative 35-basis point short rate (3-month EUR LIBOR) “received” for buying the EUR, plus 13 cross-currency basis points
paid to swap EUR for USD. On the other hand, a USD-based investor who purchases EUR assets will “earn” this additional 310 basis
points.

I'm not sure I fully understand this. I can hedge USD by simply entering into a FX Forward agreement for let's say 3 months.
After 3 months, I pay USD and receive EUR. My "profit" depends on the spot rate in 3M versus the forward rate I agreed to. So I either make money or lose money. If the spot equals the forward, then I break even.
So where exactly am I "losing" 310 basis points?

The calculation given in the text is telling you that the 3 month forward FX rate is a discount to the spot rate by an amount equal to (3.1%/4).  That is, 3.1% annual rate accrued for 3 months.
The calculation of forward fx rate depends on the interest rate differential and the currency basis, as noted.  Perhaps you were thinking that the forward fx rate is a separate phenomenon, but it isn’t.
